# Call a static method, where the method name is stored as a variable

Tags: php, class

How can I call a class's static method, when the method I want to call is stored in a variable?

For example:

```
$action = "myMethod";
MyClass::$action("some argument");
```

Which could result in the same as doing this:

```
MyClass::myMethod("some argument");
```

Comment: Take a look at Variable functions, specifically example number 3 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean Delegates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that in this way:

```
call_user_func(array('MyClass', $action), 'some argument');
```

References:

- http://php.net/call_user_func#example-5359

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure if you're talking about Delegates or not. But Storing a function/method in a Variable is called Delegates. I will post 2 examples.

```
require_once('classes.php');

$pkg = new Package("Heavy Package");
$pkg->setWeight(100);

$shipper = new ShippingDelegate();

if ($pkg->getWeight() > 99)
{
    $shipper->useRail();
}

$shipper->deliver($pkg);
```

The first one has a parameter for the Method class. The Other One calls its class Constructor.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It comes from C# which PHP already implemented. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designpatterns/ here you go, it is one of the DesignPatterns.

Comment: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/delegates Delegates have been with multiple Languages already. C# JavaScript Boo PHP Python, JAVA, Rails. 

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/delegates

Skip to 0:18 to 0:22.

Comment: You already, down marked my Answer. You expect another Answer? 1st You didn't know what a Delegate is, then you try to out knowledge me from something you just learn? Then telling me it does not require to store method in a name of a Variable? But Delegates is about storing functions in a variable. Good god. Statics in PHP doesn't really matter how you use it, because it is just treated as static variable in any function but even other methods in PHP can use it. Cause PHP does not Instantiate at all. It is PRE Processes. Watch the video 0:18 to 0:22 repeat it until you are admit you're wrong.